# How can I embed a blog in a Rails 4 application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, blogs

I am trying to create a DevBlog on my RoR site (very new to RoR). How can I go about embedding a blog from an engine like wordpress into my site? I would much prefer to do this rather than creating my own - the engine will most likely be a lot more robust.

Sorry if this is too open-ended.

Best,
Brian

Comment: Does it need to be embedded in the site? Why not just create a sub-domain of your site, e.g. blog.mysite.com, and setup a wordpress instance that you link to? Or you could use one of these: https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/Blog_Engines instead.

Comment: I believe it would be much more effective to embed it within the site. It would suit the flow much better. Any suggestions?